# window.parent.opener.document does not show required elements

Tags: javascript, gwt

I have `GWT` popup `window(page1)`, from which when a `button` is clicked, it is redirected using `window.location` to jsp(jsp1) page. And jsp1 page includes another jsp(2) page. Jsp2 page has a button when clicked, invokes a javascript method . In that method on Jsp2, i'm trying to access original GWT popup windows(page1) button elements using

```
window.parent.opener.document.getElementsByTagName("button") .
```

But it does not return any elements. Please let me know, if there is any way to access elements present in original GWT page.

Comment: why do u use window.parent.opener and not window.opener ?

Comment: Yeah window.opener too does point to GWT page, but still window.opener.document.getElementsByTagName("button") does not return button elements.

Comment: In GWT JSNI code, always refer to `$wnd` instead of needing to switch between either `window` or `window.parent` - `$wnd` and `$doc` will always refer to the window/document where the GWT script was loaded.

Comment: Colin you are right, but i'm trying to getting elements of Gwt page from javascript method invoked in Jsp2 page. And javascript method is present in actual js file where window object is use.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Invoking window.parent.opener.parent.document.getElementsByTagName("button") in javascript method from Jsp2, returns button references present in Gwt page